# Como hacer una separación en filas y columnas

Tags: javascript, html, css

estoy trabajando en una tabla donde el usuario puede estar metiendo columnas y filas, necesito que si el usuario quiere seleccionar la fila o la columna lo pueda hacer[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La imagen la edite, pero necesito que los TD estén separados del TR

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mas que nada como se muestra en esta imagen, que pueda mirarse la fila y las columnas dentro de la fila y que en todo momento pudiera seleccionar cualquier componente.

Es posible con la tabla como tal o tendría que recurrir a otras cosas, por que he puesto margin, panddin, border y otros estilos pero no logro lo que estoy buscando

Comment: Imaginemos que efectivamente selecciona la fila... ¿y ahora que?  No explicas que pretendes al seleccionar la fila o la columna

Comment: Pues ahí pudiera agregar otra columna o eliminar la misma, o agregarle color u otros elementos

Comment: vale, ¿y que código has realizado a tal efecto?  Lo digo porque aqui solucionamos problemas de código específico, no lo hacemos a medida, y no parece que aun hayas hecho nada de eso, espero equivocarme.

Comment: Mi consejo es que, para empezar, te plantees el uso de checkboxes tanto a nivel de fila como de columna, y al seleccinarlos, mediante javascript, que te salgan las opciones disponibles que estas planteando, o bien controles segun que áreas de esas filas y columnas para que mediante la captura de eventos te aparezcan esas opciones, y si son seleccionadas aplicarlas.  Pero eso lo debes hacer tu, y si te surgen problemas nos pasas el codigo y lo miramos de resolver, que es lo que nos gusta.

Comment: @masterguru Muy bien voy a investigar sobre eso de los checkboxes. Y regreso a platicar, lo que quería saber si con la tabla como tal se podía lograr, ya investigue bastante y hice pruebas con estilos y no lo pude obtener.

Comment: Tal como lo explicas, necesitas sacar un menu contextual sobre la fila o columna de algun modo, con las opciones que quieres permitir configurar, y aplicar código sobre ellas... Sera una mezcla de javascript y CSS, pero más javascript que otra cosa.  Y poder se puede, pero el codigo que necesitaras no sera trivial seguramente.

Comment: De hecho si tenia pensado el menú pero una vez seleccionado el elemento, pero a como lo comentas, tienes razón, creo que sería mas facil, ya selecciono la columna entonces con eso puedo obtener la fila y hacer lo que me comentas. Muchas gracias le voy a investigar y regreso. Saludos!!

Comment: Hola. Debes pensar el usar el atributo global **contenteditable**[https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/contenteditable]. Eso te permite ofrecer al usuario la posibilidad de editar el texto dentro de cualquier elemento html visible. Para, poder saber qué hizo el usuario debes agregar ids explícitos a los elementos editables.

Answer (score 0):

Ya llegue a una solución, como tal no pude seleccionar el TR, Pero lo que hice, fue meter una tabla dentro del TD y así poder lograr lo que necesito.

Comment: Esta respuesta no es adecuada. Te sugiero borrarla e incluir dentro de la pregunta lo adicional que hayas intentado, que te motivó a escribirla.